# PHP | Calculate remaining days but taking leap years into account

Tags: php, date

small problem to calculate the remaining days of the month starting today just I write:

```
$today = date('Y/m/d');

$timestamp = strtotime($today);

$daysRemaining = (int)date('t', $timestamp) - (int)date('j', $timestamp);

echo $daysRemaining;
```

and I get the remaining days

to do a test I entered a static date for the month of February

```
$timestamp = strtotime('2020-02-01');

$daysRemaining = (int)date('t', $timestamp) - (int)date('j', $timestamp);

echo $daysRemaining;
```

the question is here how do I calculate the remaining days in the month taking into account leap years, for example in February 2020 it will have 29 days and in this way I get out of it that remain 28

Comment: The problem is that you don't get 28 days back in feb month ??

Comment: I'm not sure I see what the problem is - your code is showing the number of days in the month minus the current day. **29 - 1** is **28**.

Comment: The problem is they're trying to do math on two formatted date strings, not calculate the amount of time between two timestamps.

Comment: @HiteshKumar I'm going back 28, but they should go back 29

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stop using the functions and start using the DateTime class!!!
This code should explain itself.

```
<?php

$x = new DateTime('2020-02-17');         // create your date
$y = clone $x;                           // copy the date
$y->modify('last day of this month');    // alter the copy to the last day

echo $x->format('d') . "\n";             // show the day of the first date
echo $y->format('d') . "\n";             // show the day of the second date
echo $y->format('d') - $x->format('d');  // show the difference between the two
```

Output:

```
17 
29 
12
```

Check it here https://3v4l.org/8ZhOb

Check the DateTime class docs here https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

Comment: sorry but I don't understand well, if for example I enter the static date of February I always get 28 instead of 29    

    $x = new DateTime("2020-02-01");
    $y = clone $x;
    $y->modify('last day of this month');

    echo $x->format('d') . "\n"; /*what day is today*/
    echo $y->format('d') . "\n"; /*how many days the month has*/
    echo $y->format('d') - $x->format('d'); /*how many days are left per month*/

Comment: ok excuse me my thoughts are on showing the days of the month, no the rest minus that of today (2020-02-01)

Comment: then just modify last day of this month, and echo date format d and you are good to go!

Comment: I'm not sure why using the DateTime class is going to change anything from the question - fundamentally if it's the **1st** and there are **29** days in the month, then there are **28** days remaining. If you want to include the current day, add one to the result.

Comment: how to include the current one?

Comment: do you just want the last day of the month, be it 29 or 28?